# Schedule Run Outlook VBA Script At Time

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, vba

This question is a different (simplified) version of this SO post ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593877/outlook-run-vba-code-at-particular-time-of-day)).

I have a particular outlook VBA script I want to run automatically at 2 PM every day (and others at multiple other times). Running client-side is fine, since the computer is always on. How can I accomplish this reliably?

The ([linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593877/outlook-run-vba-code-at-particular-time-of-day)) SO post outlines a few approaches I tried, and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580508/outlook-snooze-email-until-time-in-same-day) is a general inquiry about approaches from which my specific question about running at a time was born.

Comment: A roundabout way would be to have TS fire off a script (powershell or similar) to send an email that Outlook would look for with rules to activate a vba script.

Comment: That is a good idea, though it's not as direct as just coding a recurring script in VBA, for instance. I added an example of this as an answer below. I don't have telnet access to my company mail servers, so used a separate gmail account for the trigger.

Comment: I suggest you delete the other one. Posting the same question on the 2 sites is not on

Comment: It's a different question -- I should clarify that.

Answer (score -1):

**Summary**

We'll create a Powershell script that will send an email through Google's smtp server. This script can be run through task scheduler, which allows you to run it on a schedule. When the email is received in Outlook, a rule that looks for that email will trigger an Outlook VBA script. Viola.

**Step 1:** 
Create a secure credential file for the gmail account you will be using to send a "trigger" email to trigger the VBA script.

In Powershell, run

```
read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file $Home\autopass.txt
```

This will store a secure version of your password for that gmail account in your user directory. Note that if you use two factor authentication, you'll want to get an [app password](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords) instead of your normal password for this credential, which you'll use in the following steps.

**Step 2:**
This Powershell script will send an email through Google's smtp server using your own provided credentials. Set the fields appropriately, picking a particular very unique subject (eg, "@TRIGGERMYVBA21") that you will note in your Outlook rule.

```
   # You must paste your password after running the command:  
   # read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file $Home\autopass.txt
   # before running the next part of the script.

   #Create credential file
    $password = get-content $Home\autopass.txt | convertto-securestring
    $credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "youremail@gmail.com",$password

    #Send automatic email
    $From = "youremail@gmail.com"
    $To = "destinationemail@destination.com"
    $Subject = "@TRIGGERMYVBA21"
    $Body = "some body"
    $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    $SMTPPort = "587"

    Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject `
        -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
        -Credential ($credentials)

        # possible additions
        # $Cc = "yourboss@somedomain.com"
        # $Attachment = "dir\attachment.txt"
        # both of which require the following tags in the Send-MailMessage command
        # -Attachments $Attachment -Cc $Cc
```

Save the script as a .ps1 file.

**Step 3:** Make sure you can make rules in Outlook that can "run script" as an action. If you can't, you'll need to use regedit to go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security` and add a new DWORD (32-BIT Value) titled, `"EnableUnsafeClientMailRules"` with value 1.

**Step 4:**
Create a rule that finds:

- The gmail address of the gmail you'll be using in the Powershell script to trigger the rule
- The unique subject line you created in the Powershell script (eg, "@TRIGGERMYVBA21")

and then:

- Deletes the email,
- And runs a script

**Step 5:**
Set up a Task Scheduler rule that fires the Powershell script at the time(s) you want to run it. You'll select "start a program" as the action, then type, "powershell" for the program, and finally "-File directory\script.ps1" in the add arguments box.

For the record, I'm using this to snooze emails until they are actionable using the folder moving VBA script. I move emails to particular folders and then they are moved back into the inbox when the rule triggers for that particular folder.

That script is included here for completeness:

```
Sub moveTheItems(item As Outlook.MailItem)
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
 Dim myItem As Object

 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set myItems = myInbox.Items
 Set myDestFolder = myInbox
 Set myItems = myInbox.Folders("Snooze Until 3 PM").Items   

 For i = myItems.Count To 1 Step -1 'Iterates from the end backwards
    myItems.item(i).Move myDestFolder
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: My comment was made as you're solution wasn't VBa. You've edited the answer since

Comment: There were a few edits as I refined my solution after implementing it. It's still not ideal -- I'd prefer to create a VBA native way to do this rather than this convoluted workaround. It works though and is fully automated. I've used it daily with no errors.

Comment: Can I get an explanation on the downvotes for the answer so I can fix it? I know it's not a great solution, but it isn't poorly written in my opinion. Don't just downvote -- please help this improve.